# Stop inner iteration and find range of 2 tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

This my code, I don't know how to solve, I read some topics about, and I tried to use the break, but unfortunately without success.
The problem is,after the p2 reaches to end, it finishes the loop, but the first loop only reads 1 element.

p1,p2 are like 2 cars they start at point 1,1 and doing their route.

if the number is positive we to y.
if the number is negative we add the absolute value to x.

```
p1 = ['5', '-2', '-2', '2', '-4']
p2 = ['-3', '2', '-5', '5']
lenP1 = len(p1)-1
lenP2 = len(p2)-1
x1 = x2 = y1 = y2 = 1
p1Pos = (x1, y1)       #Initial start point
p2Pos = (x2, y2)       #Initial start point
for ir1,r1 in enumerate(p1):     #Running on first list p1
    if int(r1) > 0:       #If number is possitve 
        y1 = y1+int(r1)
        p1Pos = x1,y1

    else:
        x1 = x1+abs(int(r1))
        p1Pos = x1,y1

    for ir2,r2 in enumerate(p2):     #Running on first list p2
        if int(r2) > 0:
            y2 = y2+int(r2)
            p2Pos = x2,y2

        elif int(r2) < 0:
            x2 = x2+abs(int(r2))
            p2Pos = x2,y2 
        if ir2 ==lenP2:     #Checking if we read all integers,if so break.
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

The result should be

```
p1Pos = (9,8)
p2Pos = (9,8)
```

All points are starting at the same point (1,1) and ending the same point.

Always one starting with positive number ,and the other in negative number.

I want to find the scope to the routes of those p1,p2.
for example [image: example]

I need to save all range between p1 and p2  (the pencil lines) as tuples
How do you suggest me approach this_

Comment: Why strings in your list? Why `if ir2 ==lenP2:`? this is never going to be true because of the for loop. And mainly, what is your code doing?

Comment: I used ir2 as an index of the loop on p2, to know when it reaches to the last element. but I did it bas as I see. I described my code .
"p1,p2 are like 2 cars they start at point 1,1 and doing their route.

if the number is positive we to y. if the number is negative we add the absolute value to x."

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you seek:

```
p1 = ['5', '-2', '-2', '2', '-4']
p2 = ['-3', '2', '-5', '5']

p1Pos, p2Pos = ([1, 1], [1, 1])

def movement(p, steps):
    steps = [int(i) for i in steps]
    for step in steps:
        if step > 0:
            p[1] += step
        else:
            p[0] -= step
    return tuple(p)


p1Pos = movement(p1Pos, p1)
p2Pos = movement(p2Pos, p2)

p1Pos
#(9, 8)
p2Pos
#(9, 8)
```

Note that starting positions are initiated as lists to make them mutable, unlike tuples.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought about lists, just because the second thing that I need to do I thought better to stay  with tuples.because I want to find the scope to the routes of those p1,p2.and they are should be tuples

Comment: @LordNord I've changed `return` to give `tuple`, please see the edit.

Comment: Updated post, I don't know if I take the last position I can collect all the tuples.
Could you please navigate me to right solution, thank you